# scikit learn installed successfully but while import module not found

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip

```
Collecting sklearn
  Downloading sklearn-0.0.tar.gz (1.1 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in /Users/vineetha/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from sklearn) (0.20.4)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.2 in /Users/vineetha/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from scikit-learn->sklearn) (1.16.6)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.13.3 in /Users/vineetha/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from scikit-learn->sklearn) (1.2.3)
Building wheels for collected packages: sklearn
  Building wheel for sklearn (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for sklearn: filename=sklearn-0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=1314 sha256=d2f0ffe22a5f3a05a3a36a0f73a5ae50e26739bcbb8b23cae7c5880651288a40
  Stored in directory: /Users/vineetha/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/92/41/c1/46aa0ff43ae6274c41ffea0abc81426980f263d53d30fbc7b9
Successfully built sklearn
Installing collected packages: sklearn
Successfully installed sklearn-0.0
vineetha@vineetha Code Files % python3 BoW.py --train\_path dataset/train --test\_path dataset/test --no\_clusters 100 --kernel precomputed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vineetha/mypython_air/Vineetha_Research/ieee_extendedpaper/exp6_working/Code Files/BoW.py", line 7, in <module>
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

Answer (score 0):

You used pip to install sklearn, which by default installs it in python 2.7 as you can see here Users/vineetha/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages

You then import sklearn in python3 with python3 BoW.py

The libraries you installed for python2 are not usable in python3.

You should use

```
pip3 install sklearn
```

instead of

```
pip install sklearn
```

That way you will install it for python3.

Comment: I have used ' pip3 install -U scikit-learn scipy matplotlib ' but still throws the Module not found for sklearn error.

Comment: Do you use virtual environments? If so, you need to install it in the correct environment. Have you tried running your program in an other terminal? (after intalling sklearn, just open an other terminal in order to clear cache etc)